# WooCommerce - Change the shop address on the invoice depending on customer selected country

Tags: php, pdf, woocommerce, invoice

I am using [WooCommerce PDF Invoices](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/) plugin to create an invoice.

Problem:
I need to change the shop address on the invoice depending on the customer selected country on checkout page.

I have failed to get a working solution, at the moment I made this example:

```
$customer_shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
if(!empty($customer_shipping_country)){
   if ($customer_shipping_country == "England") {
      //change shop address to x
   } elseif ($customer_shipping_country == "France") {
      //change shop address to y
   }
}
```

Am I on the right track or?

a) to change the invoice template

b) build a hook into functions.php